# sql server print all dates between two date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table containing 3 columns. ID,Start_Date,End_Date.i want to print all the days between Start_Date and End_Date along with ID.
For Example i have table

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | Start_Date | End_Date   |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-05 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

and i want result like

```
+----+------------+
| ID | Date       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 2017-01-01 |
| 1  | 2017-01-02 |
| 1  | 2017-01-03 |
| 1  | 2017-01-04 |
| 1  | 2017-04-05 |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Common table expression :

```
   DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME = '2017-01-01'
   DECLARE @EndDT DATETIME = '2017-01-05'
   DECLARE @Id INT = 1

   ;WITH CTE (_id , _Date)AS
   (
     SELECT @Id , @StartDT
     UNION ALL
     SELECT @Id , DATEADD(DAY,1,_Date)
     FROM CTE
     WHERE _Date < @EndDT
    )

   SELECT  * FROM CTE
```

Comment: with out declaring dates can i pass column dates

Comment: +1 @nanibathineni You shall also add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end `SELECT  * FROM CTE option (maxrecursion 0)` to avoid error when date range have more than 100 days.

Answer (score 0):

Create a so called tally table (see e. g. here: https://dwaincsql.com/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/) and use it to create all dates between "from" and "to" date.

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
INTO dbo.Tally
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
go

declare @dateFrom datetime = '20170101';
declare @dateTo   datetime = '20170105';

select dateadd(day, N - 1, @dateFrom)
  from Tally
 where N between 1 and datediff(day, @dateFrom, @dateTo) + 1
```

Or:

```
select dateadd(day, t.N - 1, o.DateFrom)
  from Tally t
 cross join OtherTable o
 where t.N between 1 and datediff(day, o.DateFrom, o.DateTo) + 1
```

A tally table is very useful for such cases, it could also be filled with dates in a second column, starting from 1900-01-01 or so.

Comment: @IgoB i don't want to declare variables. i want  to get dates from table columns only

Comment: @nanibathineni : It's just an example. You can change it to your column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME = '2017-01-01'
   DECLARE @EndDT DATETIME = '2017-01-05'
   DECLARE @Id INT = 1

SELECT RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SeqNo
        ,CAST (Start_Date AS DATE) AS Start_Date
FROM (
    SELECT @StartDT + Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Rno) - 1 AS Start_Date
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS Rno
            FROM master..spt_values
        ) Dt
    ) Dt2
WHERE Dt2.Start_Date <= @EndDT
```

OutPut

```
   SeqNo    Start_Date
   --------------------
    1       2017-01-01
    1       2017-01-02
    1       2017-01-03
    1       2017-01-04
    1       2017-01-05
```